# What happens when we improve a suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review, improve-edit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

When going through the Suggested Edit queue, with my > 3K reputation on SuperUser, what happens if I select the <kbd>Improve</kbd> button and edit it? Does the edit go into effect right away since I have the reputation? Does it need the extra person to vote on it since I accessed it from the Review queue? Does it throw itself back into the queue as an entirely different suggested edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "improve" a suggested edit and no one else makes a bigger change to the post by improving the edit also then it's equivalent to you editing the post, since you have enough reputation.

The post gets instantly approved and no one else needs to vote on it.